# Springboot Application threw a java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I don't know how this SpringBoot Application reports me that

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from 'file:/E:/Workspaces/FME_BSKY/bpsoft-service-bll/server/target/classes/application.yml' (classpath:/application.yml)
```

Some say that means the app is encoded by `UTF-8` and my `application.yml` is in `GBK`, but I checked over it for over a hundred times, they are all encoded by `UTF-8`.

Comment: Post your code and additional information

Comment: there are about thousands of files here, I wanna know whether you just need the application.yml file only or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is my `application.yml` file:

```
server:
  port: 8084
  servlet:
    encoding:
      charset: UTF-8
  tomcat:
    uri-encoding: UTF-8
  http2:
    encoding:
      charset: UTF-8
      force: true
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://remotedb:3306/fme_cgn?serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai&zeroDateTimeBehavior=round&allowMultiQueries=true&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&useSSL=false&characterEncoding=utf-8&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
#    url: jdbc:mysql://localdb:3306/fme_cgn?serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai&zeroDateTimeBehavior=round&allowMultiQueries=true&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&useSSL=false&characterEncoding=utf-8&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    device-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: usn
    password: pwd

  redis:
    database: 0
    host: localhost
    password:
    port: 6379
    timeout: 0
    pool:ahfs_uploaded_file
      max-active: 8
      max-wait: -1
      max-idle: 8
      min-idle: 0
  zipkin:
    baseUrl:  baseUrl
  banner:
    charset: UTF-8
  messages:
    encoding: UTF-8
  http:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      max-file-size: 30MB
      max-request-size: 100MB
  servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      max-request-size: 100MB
      max-file-size: 30MB
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:8083/eureka/
systemPublicPath: D:\\PEC_Work_Space\\UploadedFile
defaultImageurl: D:\\PEC_Work_Space\\UploadedFile\\scan_default.png
systemUrl: http://sysUrl.cn:8084
systemType: FME
LOG_PATH: D:/FME_BSKY/log
keyToKen: 9ba8c4d3-78a4-479d-b595-ea5b330a7e73

mybatis:
  #  config-location: classpath:spring-mybatis.xml
  mapper-locations: classpath*:bpsoft/cn/mapping/basicinfo/*.xml,classpath*:bpsoft/cn/mapping/*.xml,classpath*:bpsoft/cn/mapping/fme/*.xml
```

Here is what SpringBoot told me:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from 'file:/E:/Workspaces/FME_BSKY/bpsoft-service-bll/server/target/classes/application.yml' (classpath:/application.yml)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadForFileExtension(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:468)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$null$7(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:447)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$load$8(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:447)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:444)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$load$0(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.FilteredPropertySource.apply(FilteredPropertySource.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:226)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:210)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:200)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:188)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at bpsoft.cn.Application.main(Application.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: while scanning a simple key
 in 'reader', line 26, column 5:
        pool:ahfs_uploaded_file
        ^
could not find expected ':'
 in 'reader', line 27, column 17:
          max-active: 8
                    ^

    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.stalePossibleSimpleKeys(ScannerImpl.java:464)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.needMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:278)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:226)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockMappingKey.produce(ParserImpl.java:558)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:148)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:235)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:162)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeValueNode(Composer.java:257)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingChildren(Composer.java:248)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:236)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:162)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeValueNode(Composer.java:257)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingChildren(Composer.java:248)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:236)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:162)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getNode(Composer.java:95)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getData(BaseConstructor.java:134)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml$1.next(Yaml.java:494)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader.load(OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadDocuments(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:607)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:523)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You're gonna kick yourself... `Line 26 Col 5` - its telling you exactly where to look: `pool:ahfs_uploaded_file` you didnt put a space after the colon. Its bad (yaml) syntax. Its even highlighting the particular line in the output ```Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: while scanning a simple key
 in 'reader', line 26, column 5:
        pool:ahfs_uploaded_file```

Comment: How about the wrong in the line27? I just add a space after that colon, but the wrong in line 27 stills exist.

Comment: the parser presumably thinks the colon on line 27 is for lines 26+27. Once you fix line 26 by adding a space the error on line 27 will resolve as well. If you get a new error, add it to a new answer below and we can see what's next

Answer (score 0):

Now the SpringBoot told me:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from 'file:/E:/Workspaces/FME_BSKY/bpsoft-service-bll/server/target/classes/application.yml' (classpath:/application.yml)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadForFileExtension(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:468)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$null$7(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:447)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$load$8(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:447)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:444)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$load$0(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.FilteredPropertySource.apply(FilteredPropertySource.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:226)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:210)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:200)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:188)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at bpsoft.cn.Application.main(Application.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'reader', line 27, column 17:
          max-active: 8
                    ^

    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchValue(ScannerImpl.java:870)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:358)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:227)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockMappingKey.produce(ParserImpl.java:558)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:148)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:235)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:162)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeValueNode(Composer.java:257)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingChildren(Composer.java:248)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:236)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:162)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeValueNode(Composer.java:257)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingChildren(Composer.java:248)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:236)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:162)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getNode(Composer.java:95)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getData(BaseConstructor.java:134)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml$1.next(Yaml.java:494)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader.load(OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadDocuments(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:607)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:523)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

The yaml file is:

```
server:
  port: 8084
  servlet:
    encoding:
      charset: UTF-8
  tomcat:
    uri-encoding: UTF-8
  http2:
    encoding:
      charset: UTF-8
      force: true
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://remotedb:3306/fme_cgn?serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai&zeroDateTimeBehavior=round&allowMultiQueries=true&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&useSSL=false&characterEncoding=utf-8&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
#    url: jdbc:mysql://localdb:3306/fme_cgn?serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai&zeroDateTimeBehavior=round&allowMultiQueries=true&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&useSSL=false&characterEncoding=utf-8&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    device-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: usn
    password: pwd

  redis:
    database: 0
    host: localhost
    password:
    port: 6379
    timeout: 0
    pool: ahfs_uploaded_file
      max-active: 8
      max-wait: -1
      max-idle: 8
      min-idle: 0
  zipkin:
    baseUrl:  baseUrl
  banner:
    charset: UTF-8
  messages:
    encoding: UTF-8
  http:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      max-file-size: 30MB
      max-request-size: 100MB
  servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      max-request-size: 100MB
      max-file-size: 30MB
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:8083/eureka/
systemPublicPath: D:\\PEC_Work_Space\\UploadedFile
defaultImageurl: D:\\PEC_Work_Space\\UploadedFile\\scan_default.png
systemUrl: http://sysUrl.cn:8084
systemType: FME
LOG_PATH: D:/FME_BSKY/log
keyToKen: 9ba8c4d3-78a4-479d-b595-ea5b330a7e73

mybatis:
  #  config-location: classpath:spring-mybatis.xml
  mapper-locations: classpath*:bpsoft/cn/mapping/basicinfo/*.xml,classpath*:bpsoft/cn/mapping/*.xml,classpath*:bpsoft/cn/mapping/fme/*.xml
```